# Why can't Mathematica integrate and evaluate my expression?

Tags: integration, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to compute a definite integral that I solved analytically in my class, which is:

```
Integrate[(3/2*(Cos^2)[\[Theta]] - 1/2)*(Sin^2)[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}]
```

And Mathematica can't seem to compute it, and just spits out the following:
[image: The same integral without evaluating]

This is actually the isolated problem of a bigger function, which is:

```
Qp[\[Rho]_] := (1/(4 *\[Pi]*\[Epsilon]))* (1/(r^3))*
  Integrate[\[Rho]*r^3*(3/2*(Cos^2)[\[Theta]] - 1/2)*r^2*
    Sin[\[Theta]], {r, 0, R}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*\[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 
    0, \[Pi]}]
```

```
Qp[K* R/r^2*(R - 2*r)*Sin[\[Theta]]]
```

And I have the same problem for the latter function, which is that the output is the same integral without evaluating, but only for the part concerning `\[Theta]`.

For the record, the analytical solution we found in class was -Pi/16 for the part concerning `\[Theta]` and (K⋅Pi⋅R^5)/(192⋅Epsilon⋅r^3) for the whole Qp function.

Comment: `Integrate[(3/2*Cos[\[Theta]]^2-1/2)*Sin[\[Theta]]^2, {\[Theta],0,\[Pi]}]` instantly returns `Pi/16` Mathematica definitely has an attitude about the syntax to use.

Comment: `Qp[\[Rho]_]:=1/(4*\[Pi]*\[Epsilon])*1/(r^3)*Integrate[\[Rho]*r^3*(3/2*Cos[\[Theta]]^2-1/2)*r^2*Sin[\[Theta]],{r,0,R},{\[Phi],0,2*\[Pi]},{\[Theta],0,\[Pi]}];Qp[K*R/r^2*(R-2*r)*Sin[\[Theta]]]` instantly returns `3*K*Pi*R^6/(640*r^3*\[Epsilon])`